# How to get the __content index field value in solr search

Tags: solr, content-search

I just created the site search module where I need to get all the pages that the user is looking for.

I'm able to get the item name when content matches the search term, But also I need the content field value for the description field.

I'm getting null value when I get that field, it is not stored ?

```
         var searchResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                           .Where(x => (x.Content.Contains(searchkey) || x.Name.Contains(searchkey)) && x.Path.Contains(pathToBeSearch))
                           .Where(x => x.Language == ConfigurationItem.Language.Name)
                           .Where(x => !excludeTempltes.Contains(x.TemplateName))
                           .GetResults().Hits.Select(h => h.Document).ToArray();

                            foreach (SearchResultItem item in searchResults)
                            {
                              searchdata.Page_Title = item.Name;
                              searchdata.Page_Description = item.Content;
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_content` field is not stored. It contains a lot of data from many Sitecore text fields (and media items content if it's extracted). You don't want to keep all of that inside Solr.

You can search using `_content` field like you do in your code:

```
.Where(x => (x.Content.Contains(searchkey) ...
```

but you should NOT try to get its value from the index like

```
var content = searchResultsItem.Content;
```

Instead get the value from the field of your search result item which stores `description` only, or use some other fields as a fallback. Or even get the item from Sitecore API and get what you need from the original item.

Comment: Thanks, looks cool. I will use Sitecore API to get the meta description value from that item.